# LuaRocks - Check latest available version

Tags: lua, luarocks

Is there an API/command available so I can check what is the available latest version of a rock? Similar to say `npm info xxx`.

The best I can find is `luarocks search xxx`; was hoping there would be a better endpoint that provides a better-structured response than a string.

**Update**

Also, using `luarocks search xxx` does not do an exact match. For example, running `luarocks search multipart` returns 4 results because of `multipart` matches for names. But I do want to do an exact search; there is a package called `multipart`. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

`luarocks show` ([described here](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/show)) has a `--mversion` flag that will return the current package version.

Otherwise, `luarocks search` is, as you already know, your option for querying what rocks (and their versions) are available.